# Calculating IOPS in a SQL Server EC2 - RDS migration

Tags: sql-server, amazon-rds, amazon-ec2

I'm evaluating costs for a possible migration of a SQL Server that is currently running on Amazon EC2 to Amazon RDS. On the EC2 instance I have six volumes, described as follows:

| type | size | IOPS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| gp2 | 100 GB | 300 |
| io1 | 250 GB | 1700 |
| io1 | 550 GB | 1700 |
| gp2 | 100 GB | 300 |
| io1 | 700 GB | 1700 |
| io1 | 1750 GB | 4700 |

I can't specify the same six volumes on the RDS price calculator. I get just one field for the storage. Regarding the space, easy-peasy, just sum it. But, how about the IOPS? Should I just opt for the largest (4700 in this case), or should I sum all of them?

Comment: You should sum them together

Comment: Are you actually using the full IOPS capacity on all of those disks? That graph shows the _capacity_, but if you aren't using that capacity, then you don't necessarily need the same capacity once you consolidate it.